# Sort data alphabetically and pass to a view using Expressjs and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to pass the data I get from the DB to a view using expressjs and mongodb, however I'd like to sort the data alphabetically.

I know I can get that through the mongo sell using the following command:

```
db.registers.find().sort({name:1})
```

But I didn't figure out how to get the data sorted and put it on the view page. Could someone please help me out?!

Thanks in advance!

**Trying to fetch the data alphabetically:**

```
// Fetching the data
app.get('/registers', (req, res) => {
  Register.find({}).sort({name:1})
    .then(registers => {
      res.render('registers/index')
      registers:registers
    })

})
```

**The view page where I want to show the data sorted:**

```
<h1>Register</h1>
{{#each registers}}
  <div class="card card-body">
    {{name}}
  </div>
{{else}}
  <p>No registers</p>
{{/each}}
```

**The model:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const RegisterSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  phone: String,
  gender: String,
  birth: String,
  cpf: String,
})

mongoose.model('registers', RegisterSchema)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering in case anyone needs help with the same...

**Correct syntax to fetch the dada:**

```
// Fetching the data
app.get('/registers', (req, res) => {
  let sorty = {name : 1}
  Register.find({}).sort(sorty)
    .then(registers => {
      res.render('registers/index', {
        registers:registers
      })
    })  
})
```